# Chrome Webdriver Imprimir modo "--headless"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Buen día, estoy realizando una automatización de impresión de etiquetas con Python y selenium. Tengo todo funcionando perfecto, salvo la parte de la impresión de las mismas. Si el webdriver lo ejecuto con el parámetro '--kiosk-printing' (para evitar el cuadro de dialogo de impresión) funciona perfectamente, pero si lo ejecuto con el parámetro chrome_options.add_argument('--headless') (el cual es el que me interesa para ocultar el navegador), nunca sale la impresión. Encontré información para enviar la impresión a un archivo PDF, pero nada sobre enviar a impresora predetermina.¿es posible esto que estoy intentando?

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: No estoy seguro de si es un bug o un problema de chrome. Has probado firefox en lugar de chrome?

Comment: No, voy a probarlo y comento el resultado. Gracias!

Comment: Al parecer no es posible en modo headless, pero alguna vez lo solucione imprimiendo a PDF, y luego enviar el archivo PDF a la impresora por linea de comandos.

Comment: Por el momento lo solucione como menciono F.igor, descargo el archivo en una carpeta y luego lo mando a imprimir, como lo muestra aqui "Alex Lord Mordor" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27195594/python-silent-print-pdf-to-specific-printer. Gracias!